# Ability to find WinForm control via the Tag property

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in C# on an existing WinForm project.  The original code uses Tag to convey hardware addressing info for a bunch of textboxes that represent certain hardware registers in a connected microcontroller system.  I know how to find an unknown control by searching for its Name using the Control.ControlCollection.Find method, but it's unclear to me on whether I can find the control by the Tag (just a string in this instance).

Comment: Iterate over the Control collection and check for the specific tag value?

Comment: You should change your design, we should not perform such a task. Of course you have to loop through all the controls and check the `Tag` of each one until you find it. The internal implementation of `Find` should do the same thing. The speed all depends on the `data structure` inside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow up on my comment:

```
private void FindTag(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        if (c.Tag != null)
        //logic

       if (c.HasChildren)
           FindTag(c.Controls); //Recursively check all children controls as well; ie groupboxes or tabpages
    }
}
```

Then you can get the control name in the if statement and do whatever you want to do from there.

Just adding an Edit to this solution as it still gets the infrequent Upvote a few years later. You can also modify this solution to check the *type* of control that `c` is and do different kinds of logic as well. So if you want to loop over all your controls and handle a `Textbox` one way and a `RadioButon` another way you can do that as well. I've had to do that on a few projects as well, where I was able to just slightly change the code above to make that work. Not necessarily relevant to the OP's question, but thought I'd add it.

Comment: My answer had a limitation. It is not recursive.

Comment: @Tilak, your initial solution was very efficient in the case where recursion was not needed.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MD Glad to help. Did pescolino's answer work? His may or may not be a little nicer since it actually returns the control, and also if you have multiple controls with tag properties set then you can search for just that as specific tag, as opposed to my answer here "catching" any tag.

Comment: @MD, undeleted my answer in the interest of future visitors (for cases where recursion is not needed)

Comment: The [Control class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control(v=vs.110).aspx) does not seem to have a `Tag` property.

Comment: @MarcoLackovic World's most delayed response: [System.Windows.Forms.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.7.2) does have a Tag property. This question was tagged as a `winforms` question, you linked the System.**Web**.UI Control class.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `LINQ` to find controls based on `Tag`

```
var items = parentControl.ControlCollection;
var item = items.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(control => String.Equals(control.Tag, tagName));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public static Control FindByTag(Control root, string tag)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (root.Tag is string && (string)root.Tag == tag)
    {
        return root;
    }

    return (from Control control in root.Controls
            select FindByTag(control, tag)).FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

Pass the outermost control to it (i.e. the form or container you want to search through). Note that this includes the root control into the search.