# c# enable button only if All fields are filled in Text boxes

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm pretty stuck here and I need help.
I got a lot of text boxes in my form, some visible and some invisible.

I want that Button2 will be active only when all text boxes (that are not hidden) are not empty (At least one character or number)

I saw all kinds of codes, but I could not figure out how to do it. (and it's not working for me)

For example here's a code  that I tried, but it did not work out.

```
 bool invalid = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
         .Where(t => t.Visible)
          .Any(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text));

        if (invalid)
            button2.Enabled = false;
```

I would also like an explanation if it possible.

Thank you!

Comment: are all `TextBox` controls parented by the form? "did not work out" - what does that mean?

Comment: In which event do you execute this code?

Comment: @steve -  public void NEW_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Comment: I can only think that one (or more) of your TextBoxes are inside a panel or groupbox and are not found by the search on the controls collection of the form.

Comment: Is it the user filling the form or the code?

Answer (score 0):

A recursive method that iterates over all controls on the form and looks for visible / enabled Textboxes is how I'd do it:

```
private void AreControlsValid(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{   
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        if (c is Textbox && c.Visible)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(((Textbox)c).Text))
                return false;
        }

       if (c.HasChildren)
           AreControlsValid(c.Controls);
    }

    return true;
}
```

*Didn't test, this is an adaptation of an answer I posted in another thread: [Ability to find WinForm control via the Tag property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775899/1189566)

**edit**: Also you'd probably want an generic event that all your textboxes subscribe to along the lines of:

```
textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Enabled = AreControlsValid(this.Controls);
}
```

As Steve mentioned in a comment, the problem with `MyForm.Controls` is that it only gets direct children controls on your form, it does not get those children's children. So if you have a form, with a groupbox, with textboxes, `MyForm.Controls` will get you the groupbox and not the textboxes. That's why mine is recursive; it goes all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use this procedure to set the button's availability (imagine there are only three textboxes):

```
private void SetButton()
{
    button2.Enabled = (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox1.Visible == false) && (textBox2.Text != "" || textBox2.Visible == false) && (textBox3.Text != "" || textBox3.Visible == false);
}
```

For each textbox, it returns a true boolean if the textbox is filled or is invisible. In order to make sure it takes effect immediately, I would double click each textbox on the designer file to get the "textBox(number)_TextChanged" eventhandler, and then call the procedure that I just made. For example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetButton();
}
```

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This quickly becomes messy with larger scale applications that have many textboxes on a form, not only from a readability standpoint but a maintainability staindpoint as well. Also you can just do `!textBox1.Visible`

Comment: I agree, I was just trying to create a simpler version because it seems this person is new to programming. Normally I would have some kind of loop that goes through all the textboxes or something.

Comment: Ah ok, just saw the 108 Reputation and assumed you were newer as well!

Comment: I am reasonably new compared to some I suppose. Been doing C# for a little of two years but I feel I've only just scratched the surface.

Comment: @sab669 - For some of us the rep shows how long we have been on SO and not how long we've been coding.  :)

`+1` on maintainability comment.  OP said he had lots of textboxes.

Comment: Oh yeah, fair enough :p.

Comment: @dbagley Oh I know, but they are often times not unrelated. Especially if you get the free 100 rep from another StackExchange site

Comment: I thought the rep from other sites were kept separate. I use the music theory one as well and that hasn't transferred over to this.

Comment: That's something I didn't know about either!   :)