# Calculate Index in a custom grid

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a old-themed RPG with WinForms and I would need something like a *grid* to accomplish the wall and field checking. By *grid* I would mean something like this (where at the positions I then put the graphics):

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06  
07 08 09 10 11 12 13  
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

I already did this and it works pretty good. Now to check the wall-collisions I need to find out the position of the player in this grid.  I somehow figured out this formula:

```
int index = (p.Location.X / p.Width) + ((p.Location.Y / p.Height) * (width));
```

`p` being the pictureBox and `width` the amount of fields on the Y-Scale. All the pictureboxes and Images have the size 64x64. Unfortunately this formula doesnt give me the correct result. If I (on testing) am on the `13` index it tells me I am on the `14` index.

**Question:**
Do you know *any* way to improve this formula or to simply make it work?
*Any* help is appreciated ;)

Comment: What type of controls are you using? Is this a `DataGridView`, `ImageList`,  `ListView` or just a bunch of `PictureBox` controls in a grid-like layout with no containing control [aside from the form itself]? Or something else entirely...

Comment: @sab669 A grid-like layout, because I am adding the tiles depending on the read-in map data.

Comment: Ok so basically you generate the `PictureBox` on the fly during run time and drop it into position? What if you simply assign a value to the control's `Tag` property representing its location in the grid? Then as your player object, or whatever it is, moves, you can just [get a control by its Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19775899/1189566) and switch `Tag` values to update the new position. Then you can just set a bunch of parameters to ensure there's a valid adjacent tile before they try to move.

Comment: Just expanding on my previous comment, basically if you know you have 7 pictures / tiles in a row in your grid, check (psuedocode) `if (ValidTileAtLocationByTagValue(PlayerPictureBox.Tag - 7)) then Move(Player.Tag, Direction.Up)` or whatever, where `ValidTileAtLocationByTagValue` uses the loop I linked to try and find a `PictureBox` with the given value passed, and will check if it exists at all,  if it's a wall tile, if it's an open space or a monster and initiate combat etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to doing the calculation is a bit off.

The general formula for calculating the index of a cell on a grid is:

```
index = (cell_row * columns_in_grid) + cell_column
```

Given the location and size of the cell as well as the size of grid, the formula becomes:

```
index = ((cell_Y / cell_Height) * (grid_Width / cell_Width)) + (cell_X / cell_Width)
```

Now, translating it to your scenario, with the assumption that the PictureBox `p` is placed directly on its parent control, the index can be calculated as:

```
index = ((p.Location.Y / p.Height) * (p.Parent.Width / p.Width)) + (p.Location.X / p.Width);
```

---

Since I've got a bit of free time on my hands, here is a small demo I wrote for you:

#### Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button btn;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btn = new Button()
        {
            Text = "0",
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            Size = new Size(30, 30),
        };

        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        this.ClientSize = new Size(btn.Width * 7, btn.Height * 3);

        btn.Move += btn_Move;
        this.MouseClick += Form1_MouseEvent;
        this.MouseWheel += Form1_MouseEvent;
    }

    private void btn_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Text = CalculateIndex().ToString();
    }

    private int CalculateIndex()
    {
        return ((btn.Location.Y / btn.Height) * (btn.Parent.Width / btn.Width)) + 
               (btn.Location.X / btn.Width);
    }

    void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // moving horizontally with left and right buttons
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            btn.Left -= btn.Width;
        else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            btn.Left += btn.Width;

        // moving vertically with mouse wheel
        else if (e.Delta > 0)
            btn.Top -= btn.Height;
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
            btn.Top += btn.Height;
    }
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Cell index demo]

#### Controls

Control the position by performing the following actions on the form:
**Right-click:** Move right
**Left click:** Move left
**Scroll up (with mouse wheel):** Move upwards
**Scroll down (with mouse wheel):** Move downwards
**Double click:** Return the button to the initial location

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a 2 dimensional array to hold your map data.  That way you can calculate which element they player is in by dividing their co-ordinates by the size of a tile.  You can simply reference that location in the array directly then.

```
int[,] map = new int[7, 3];  // Create an array of same size as you example grid

data = map[x, y]; // reference the value stored in co-ordinates represented by x and y
```

Converting a pixel position to a grid reference should be a case of dividing the actual pixel x&y co-ordinates by the size of the title

Of course the array could be of a structure so you could have elements at each location that represent what is on that square (items, walls, doors, traps etc).

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is `data`? Is it a PictureBox Location for items, walls, doors?

Comment: data would be whatever value was stored for that location.  It would be entirely up to you what you wanted stored there.  For example, you could say have the value 0 = empty floor, 1 = wall, 2 = monster.. etc.  Then you can check co-ordinates to see what is there.